# want custom title image description in facebook share link in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, facebook-share

I'm creating a facebook share button in my web application. My requirement is when the user fills the form with image upload I want this is to be share to facebook

Apparently Facebook Share doesn't pick up the title/description meta tags that are changed (via JavaScript), because of that I used view bag variable in MVC to change the variables. still title, description, image is not changing.
Any Alternate method is there with custom title, description, and image

```
 <a href="" onclick="shareOnFB()">Share</a>
```

This is my Js code:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'appId',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.8'
        });
    };
    shareOnFB = function () {
        var desc = "@ViewBag.description";
        var title = "@ViewBag.title";
        var link = "@ViewBag.url";
        var image = "@ViewBag.Image";
        FB.ui({
            method: 'share_open_graph',
            action_type: 'og.shares',
            action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                object: {
                    'og:url': link,
                    'og:title': title,
                    'og:description': desc,
                    'og:Image': image,
                    'og:image:width': 540,
                    'og:image:height': 281

                }
            })
        }),
            function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            };
    };
</script>
```